# Order confirmation email is in english for custom payment method in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment, translate, locale

I have an m2 website in the Norwegian language when an order is placed with COD then the order confirmation email is Norwegian but when I use my custom payment method the order confirmation email is in english.
how can I translate email text?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Surajan try to create a new template in Norwegian language
https://magefan.com/blog/translate-email-templates-in-magento-2
follow this link it may help you

Comment: I have single store view in the Norwegian language when  I place an order using COD then email in Norwegian but when  I place an order using a custom payment method then email is in English